# Quaternion rotation in coroutine does not work properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, coroutine

Alright, I'm trying to make an object called 'pathblock' rotate 90 degrees clockwise every time the player presses 'E'. The player should be able to spam the button, with the block turning 360 degrees without fail.

I want to see the rotation animation, so I am using coroutine in combination with a slerp function. The coroutine is called in update, if E is pressed.

```
//Rotates the selected pathblock by 90 degrees over a specified time. A coroutine is necessary to render each slerp() result per seperate frame
IEnumerator RotatePathblock()
{
    Debug.Log("Start rotation!");
    Quaternion start = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(pathblock.transform.rotation.x, pathblock.transform.rotation.y, pathblock.transform.rotation.z)); //Set start variable for Slerp(), the current rotation of the pathblock
    Quaternion end = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(start.x, start.y, start.z-90.0f));

    Debug.Log(string.Format("Target Angle: {0}", end.eulerAngles.z));


    float normalizationFactor = 1.0f / pathblockRotationTime; //We need to normalize time since slerp() works with values between 0-1; we can convert values by multiplying with this factor
    float timePassed = 0.0f; //Time passed since the start of the linear interpolation. Starting at 0, it increases until it reaches 1. All values are rendered.

    while(timePassed < 1.0f) //While the time passes is less than 1 (the maximum of a linear interpolation)
    {
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime * normalizationFactor; //Increase the timePassed with the time passed since the last frame; the time is first normalized
        pathblock.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(start, end, timePassed); //Set the pathblock rotation to a new value defined by linear interpolation
        yield return null; //Stop the function, finish Update() and return to this while loop; this will cause all slerp() values to render, resulting in a smooth animation
    }
}
```

The first press turns the pathblock 90 degrees, as expected.
The second press sets the pathblock back to its original rotation, and turns it 90 degrees again. 
This leads me to believe that the 'start' variable never changes, even though it should set itself to the new pathblock.transform.rotation when the function is called, getting the new rotation.

If anyone could look at what's wrong, I'd appreciate it.
Any other critique on my code, comments etc. would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Quaternion start = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(pathblock.transform.rotation.x, pathblock.transform.rotation.y, pathblock.transform.rotation.z)); //Set start variable for Slerp(), the current rotation of the pathblock
```

Should be:

```
Quaternion start = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(pathblock.transform.eulerAngles.x, pathblock.transform.eulerAngles.y, pathblock.transform.eulerAngles.z)); //Set start variable for Slerp(), the current rotation of the pathblock
```